# Show/hide without using CSS

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have the following sample. I want to achieve by changing the CSS properties. How can I do it?

```
    <div id="btn-toggle-menu">Menu</div>
       <div id="menu-wrapper">
         <ul>
           <li>link item</li>
           <li>link item</li>
           <li>link item</li>
           <li>link item</li>
           <li>link item</li>
           <li>link item</li>
         </ul>
       </div>
```

jQuery:

```
    $('#menu-wrapper').hide();

    $('#btn-toggle-menu').on('click', function(e) {
    var menu = $('#menu-wrapper');
      if(menu.is(':hidden')) {
        menu.show();
      } else {
        menu.hide();
      }
  });
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Anusha_Mallajosyula/FWzAS/8/)

Comment: That seems like a lot of code to show / hide. Check out http://api.jquery.com/toggle/

Comment: do you mean http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/3bUph/1/

Comment: You can do $('#meu-wrapper').css ('display', 'none');

Comment: use visibility:hidden property

Comment: Without CSS, that was something generally people don't want to.. they prefer CSS solutions over JS

Comment: the title and the question itself contradict.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jquery's  `Hide` & `Show` behave like CSS's `display:none` & `display: [the default display value of the element]`

[**Working Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/avrahamcool/FWzAS/10/) *<-- with minimum changes* (I would actually use [this](http://jsfiddle.net/avrahamcool/FWzAS/11/))

Answer (score 1):

Try the [JQuery .toggle()](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/)

```
$( "#btn-toggle-menu" ).click(function() {
  $( "#menu-wrapper" ).toggle( "slow", function() {
    // Animation complete.
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

try jquery

```
$( "#btn-toggle-menu" ).click(function() {
  $( "#menu-wrapper" ).toggle();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok here.

```
<div id="btn-toggle-menu">Menu</div>
   <div id="menu-wrapper">
     <ul>
       <li>link item</li>
       <li>link item</li>
       <li>link item</li>
       <li>link item</li>
       <li>link item</li>
       <li>link item</li>
     </ul>
   </div>
```

This is your code?

Using jQuery you can select which element takes which property on which event. jQuery actually do toggle the CSS properties. So what you want would be achieved once you are specifying correct `event` `element` and `css-property`.

Have a look:

Here the `event` will be a `click` and the element to shift its `display` will be `ul`.

You want to show/hide the `ul`. So this would do the job.

```
$('#btn-toggle-menu').click(function() { // on the click event
  $('#menu-wrapper').toggle(); // toggle would hide/show it. on its own :)
})
```

You can learn about this here: http://api.jquery.com/toggle/

**Note:** You must have the jQuery plugin for this. To make sure the jQuery events would occur. You can download the plugin in the footer of the site I provided. :) Good luck!

**Your code:**

Your code is also good, but its alot lengthy and more like hard-coded!

```
$('#menu-wrapper').hide();

$('#btn-toggle-menu').on('click', function(e) {
var menu = $('#menu-wrapper');
  if(menu.is(':hidden')) {
    menu.show();
  } else {
    menu.hide();
  }
});
```

This will first have a look on the menu, if its hidden then it will show! Otherwise hide it. That's good and correct! But a bit lengthy, jQuery API would help you solve this easily. Using their plugin. Download it from the link at the bottom, the latest plugin would let you use all the latest features of jQuery. :)

**Edit I made in your code:**

I just editted the jQuery code from your fiddle and this was the result:

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/afzaal_ahmad_zeeshan/FWzAS/13/). Here I was able to hide/show the div :) And it was just one line code!