# show/Hide without using hide() and show()

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have this right now. I want to achieve the functionality of hide/show without using the functions. Is it possible using

```
visibility:hidden
```

? Kindly provide me a  [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/Anusha_Mallajosyula/FWzAS/26/)

**HTML**

```
<div id="btn-toggle-menu">Hide Menu</div>
<div id="menu-wrapper">
    <ul>
        <li>link item</li>
        <li>link item</li>
        <li>link item</li>
        <li>link item</li>
        <li>link item</li>
        <li>link item</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#btn-toggle-menu').click(function() {
        var hidden = $('#menu-wrapper').data('hidden');
        $('#btn-toggle-menu').text(hidden ? 'Hide Menu' : 'Show Menu');
        if(hidden)
        {
            $('#menu-wrapper').animate({left: '20px' },500)
        } 
        else {
            $('#menu-wrapper').animate({
                left: '-210px'
            },500)
        }
        $('#menu-wrapper').data("hidden", !hidden);
    });
});
```

Comment: Please tell us WHY so we can help you better. If you want to hide but not remove, animate the opacity

Comment: you are not using `.hide()` or `.show()` anywhere. Your explanation is not clear to me..

Comment: @mplungjan If I use hide() and show() it is breaking some code. The code which I posted is only a sample.

Comment: Mr_Green I am not using it now. But, to achieve the functionality of hide() and show() I want an alternative.

Comment: [possible duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18973982/show-hide-without-using-css/18974126#18974126)

Comment: what you have now is not using hide/show

Answer (score 1):

I think you may be looking for the CSS properties

```
display: none;
```

and

```
display: block;
```

That's what jQuery does behind the scenes.

Answer (score 1):

Using visibility, if you don't want the element to take up space (as a truly hidden element won't), you need to position it absolute, as well.

Try this:

```
if(hidden) {
    $('#menu-wrapper').css({
        visibility: 'visible',
        position: 'fixed'
    });
} else {
    $('#menu-wrapper').css({
        visibility: 'hidden',
        position: 'absolute'
    });
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/philwills/FWzAS/28/

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use pure css, you can use something like this..

The CSS

```
 <style type="text/css">
  .show {display: none; }
  .hide:focus + .show {display: inline; }
  .hide:focus { display: none; }
  .hide:focus ~ #list { display:none; }
  @media print { .hide, .show { display: none; } }
</style>
```

HTML

```
  <div>
     <a href="#" class="hide">Hide Menu</a>
     <a href="#" class="show">Show Menu</a>
     <ul id="list">
        <li>Link Item 1</li>
        <li>Link Item 1</li>
        <li>Link Item 1</li>
     </ul>
  </div>
```

Here is the [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/JFrBA/4/)

Comment: I want onclick not hover..

Comment: i have updated the answer..kindly check the working demo...But this will only work with the mouse button down...
You must need to use a little bit of script....

Comment: the menu should not disappear on mouseup

Comment: @AnushaMallajosyula
This will surely work for you

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
#btn-toggle-menu:active + #menu-wrapper{
    display:none/block; 
}
```